# gganimate round values during transition

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, rounding, gganimate

I want to create an animated barplot with the gganimate package. At the top of each bar, I want to put the value of the bar rounded to zero digits.

Consider the following example:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(ordering = c(rep(1:3, 2), 3:1, rep(1:3, 2)),
                 year = factor(sort(rep(2001:2005, 3))),
                 value = round(runif(15, 0, 100)),
                 group = rep(letters[1:3], 5))

# Create animated ggplot
ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = ordering, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group)) +
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 2, state_length = 0) +
  geom_text(y = df$value, label = as.integer(round(df$value)))
ggp
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I did not manage to round the values properly. Is there a way to round values during transition?

Comment: `round(runif(15, 0, 100),0)`? **Not sure**

Comment: @NelsonGon Unfortunately, that does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055118/gganimate-geom-text-with-numeric-values-animates-at-decimal-numbers-instead-of I don't think there is some option to do that at the moment, but there is a "manual" solution on this question you could easily adapt.

Comment: @Freguglia Thank you for your response! The problem with the manual solution provided in the other thread is that the duration of the horizontal transition of the bars would be shortened. In the suggested thread there is no horizontal transition and therefore the solution works for the barchart of the other thread, but not for mine. Do you know a way how I could retain the horizontal transition duration?

Comment: open issue https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/204

Answer (score 5):

Since df$value is already rounded to zero decimals via round() you can use as.character() when setting your labels.

```
> df$value
[1] 29 81 92 50 43 73 40 41 69 15 11 66  4 69 78
> as.character(df$value)
[1] "29" "81" "92" "50" "43" "73" "40" "41" "69" "15" "11" "66" "4"  "69" "78"
```

Result:

```
ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = ordering, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group)) +
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 2, state_length = 0) +
  geom_text(label = as.character(df$value))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem with your solution is that the values are not reflecting the movement in between, but only the fixed points that are defined in the input data. Do you know a way how the values could reflect the transition movement?