# gganimate tween values showing hexadecimal values

Tags: r, gganimate

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162821/animated-sorted-bar-chart-with-bars-overtaking-each-other) I am trying to create an animated bar plot, but the bar label tween values are showing hexadecimal values:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gganimate)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  period = rep(1:3, each = 5),
  x = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3),
  p = rbeta(15, 3, 2)
)

data <- df %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  mutate(rank = min_rank(-p)) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(data, aes(x = rank)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(y = p / 2, 
                height = p,
                width = 0.75)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = p,
                label = scales::percent(p, 1)),
            hjust = 0,
            nudge_y = 0.005) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = F) + 
  scale_x_reverse() + 
  labs(title = 'Period {closest_state}',
       x = "",
       y = "") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(r = 5, unit = "cm")) + 
  transition_states(period) + 
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

---

**Things I have tried**

1. As this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224154/6382434) suggests I have tried `label = round(p * 100)`.
2. I have tried to create character labels in `df`: `df$labs <- paste0(round(df$p * 100), "%")` and then using them in the `geom_text` label instead of `p`.

**Questions**

I have two questions:

1. How do I correct these tween values so they properly display as rounded percentages?
2. Is there a way to hide tween values and only show the true values once a transition state is reached (e.g., at Period 1, Period 2, and Period 3 only)?

Comment: I am using `gganimate 1.0.7` and it renders for me without that labeling error. For me, the label switches once midway through the transition.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue using `gganimate 1.0.8`. (:

Comment: I am using `1.0.8` but I downgraded to `1.0.7` and still encountered this issue. I am also using `ggplot2 3.3.5`, `dplyr 1.0.7`, and `scales 1.1.1`.

Comment: @JonSpring can you tell me what version of `gifski` you are running? I am running `1.6.6.1`.

Comment: Huh, looks like on this computer (a mac) I didn't have gifski installed at all, so I'm guessing it triggers another renderer. I would have expected the error you're seeing would have developed upstream of that. I restarted R, installed gifski 1.6.6-1, re-ran code, and still looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments, I figured there are some "special" `character` values that cause this hexadecimal label glitch during animation. I still don't know **why** this happens, but at least there's a workaround. Here's the full story:

If I try to animate the character `"1M"`, the issue is there:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d1 <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),state=c(1,2),label=c("1M","1M"))

ggplot(data=d1,mapping=aes(x=x,y=2,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But the character `"M"` is animated with no issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),state=c(1,2),label=c("M","M"))

ggplot(data=d2,mapping=aes(x=x,y=2,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So there's something special about `"1M"` that causes a glitch. The same happens with color names:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d3 <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),state=c(1,2),label=c("green","green"))

ggplot(data=d3,mapping=aes(x=x,y=2,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But not for a non-color character, like `"green10"`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d4 <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),state=c(1,2),label=c("green10","green10"))

ggplot(data=d4,mapping=aes(x=x,y=2,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If a "special" character needs to transition to a "non-special" one, it spits an error:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d5 <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),state=c(1,2),label=c("1M","M"))

ggplot(data=d5,mapping=aes(x=x,y=2,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
#> Error: The labelcolumn differs in type between the two inputs
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And finally, the **workaround** - padding the "special" characters with spaces:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d6 <- data.frame(x=c(0,1),state=c(1,2),label=c(" 1M "," 1M "))

ggplot(data=d6,mapping=aes(x=x,y=2,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Interestingly, the issue disappears if there's one "non-special" character in the data:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

d <- data.table(label=c("1M","green"," 1M "),
                x1=0,x2=1,y=c(1,2,3)) |>
  melt(measure.vars=c("x1","x2"),variable.name="state",value.name="x")

print(d)
#>    label y state x
#> 1:    1M 1    x1 0
#> 2: green 2    x1 0
#> 3:   1M  3    x1 0
#> 4:    1M 1    x2 1
#> 5: green 2    x2 1
#> 6:   1M  3    x2 1

ggplot(data=d,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,label=label)) +
  geom_text() + transition_states(states=state)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So, a simple remedy to your issue using `paste0`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(gganimate)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  period = rep(1:3, each = 5),
  x = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3),
  p = rbeta(15, 3, 2)
)

data <- df %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  mutate(rank = min_rank(-p)) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(data, aes(x = rank)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(y = p / 2, 
                height = p,
                width = 0.75)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = p,
                label = paste0(" ",scales::percent(p, 1)," ")),
            hjust = 0,
            nudge_y = 0.005) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = F) + 
  scale_x_reverse() + 
  labs(title = 'Period {closest_state}',
       x = "",
       y = "") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(r = 5, unit = "cm")) + 
  transition_states(period) + 
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I'm curious to know if there's a logic to what other `characters` cause this glitch and why. So far, it's any number+N, number+B, number+k, number+%, and color names (or that happens for me at least).